# Inserting in to an unordered_map of unordered_map?

Tags: c++, c++11, unordered-map

I have a data structure which is an unordered_map of unordered_map:

```
typedef std::unordered_map<string, int> map1;
typedef std::unordered_map<string, map1> map2;
```

and I would like to insert an element in to map1, without needing to use IF statements to check whether it already exists. However, I am a bit confused because map2 doesn't have a value unless you already have the map1 element, but the map1 element comes from map2 (if it already exists there).

What is the cleanest way to do this?

Comment: Does `the_map[i][j] = val` not work?

Answer (score 6):

If you don't use pointers you could simply use `operator[]` on both maps.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>

typedef std::unordered_map<std::string, int> map1;
typedef std::unordered_map<std::string, map1> map2;

int main()
{
    map2 m2;
    m2["a"]["b"] = 1;

    std::cout << m2["a"]["b"] << std::endl;
}
```

If there is the case with only `map2*` you could do as follows

```
int main()
{
    map2* m1 = new map2();
    map2& m2 = *m1;
    m2["a"]["b"] = 1;

    std::cout << m2["a"]["b"] << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Hi, using your example, I have a map2* pointer, not a map2 object

Comment: @user997112 I have updated my answer, if the `map2*` is the only problem then you could try to use my solution. However it's becoming worse if you have `std::unordered_map<std::string, map1*>` type.

Comment: @user997112 If you have a pointer then you can also write `(*m1)["a"]["b"] = 1;`